# How to test if parameterized method throws chai and mocha?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I have this (simplified) code to test:

```
function verifyArg(x) {
  if (x == 400) throw new Error("Bad Parameter!")
}
```

How do I test if the error is thrown correctly with mocha and chai?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself:

```
describe("verify()", function() {
   it("throws on 400", function() {
      expect(function() {
         verify(400);
      }).not.to.throw();
   });
});
```

callback hell ftw!